# Calculate percentile of price in the same cities and hoods per cust

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

This is my cust table:

| rn | cust_id | price | street_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2468 | 100 | 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 1234 | 200 | 1 | 16 |
| 3 | 5678 | 300 | 1 | 16 |
| 4 | 7890 | 20 | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | 2346 | 70 | 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 4532 | 10 | 5 | 9 |

I want to add a "percentile" column with this calculation per hood id and city_id, for example:

- 100/(100+200+300)= 0.16667
- 200/(100+200+300)= 0.33333
- 300/(100+200+300)= 0.500

**output:**

| rn | cust_id | price | street_id | city_id | percentile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2468 | 100 | 1 | 16 | 0.16667 |
| 2 | 1234 | 200 | 1 | 16 | 0.33333 |
| 3 | 5678 | 300 | 1 | 16 | 0.50 |
| 4 | 7890 | 20 | 5 | 9 | 0.2 |
| 5 | 2346 | 70 | 5 | 9 | 0.7 |
| 6 | 4532 | 10 | 5 | 9 | 0.1 |

**I thought to use the percentile function but it's not working.**

If someone has a good idea it will be amazing :)

Comment: So, what did you put in the percentile function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use the division between price and a window function that computes the sum over each partition of <city_id, street_id>.

```
SELECT *, price / SUM(price) OVER(PARTITION BY city_id, street_id) AS percentile 
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/esqx6r3qB81EeS9XuFcf3z/0).

---

In MySQL 5.X, you need a subquery to compute your maximum values for each partition, then join back with your original table and apply the division.

```
SELECT tab.*, tab.price / cte.total_price AS percentile
FROM       tab 
INNER JOIN (SELECT city_id, street_id, 
                   SUM(price) AS total_price
            FROM tab
            GROUP BY city_id, street_id) cte
        ON tab.city_id = cte.city_id AND tab.street_id = cte.street_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/esqx6r3qB81EeS9XuFcf3z/1).